# How to extract a number between two different characters in Excel?

Tags: excel

I want to extract this number: "456" for example from the string below:

> "abc def ! 123z ghi ! 456z @ jkl"

The number that I want to extract always comes **after "! "** and **before "z @"** string

thanks

Comment: While you probably _could_ do this in pure Excel, what you really need here is some kind of regex support, which Excel does not have out of the box.  Therefore, I recommend handling this problem from VBA, assuming you have access to it.

Comment: I need to handle this without using VBA

Comment: And what have you tried so far? Also, would there always just be one occurence of `z @` in the string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
=--TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"! ",REPT(" ",LEN(A1))),FIND("z @",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"! ",REPT(" ",LEN(A1))))-LEN(A1),LEN(A1)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you could look at :

Edited and corrected:

```
=MID(A2,FIND("! ",A2,FIND("! ",A2,1)+1)+2,LEN(A2)-(FIND(" @",A2,1)+2))
```

[image]

This is as short as I can get it... But it does assume that there will always be two "! " in the string prior to the target number...

Now edited to trap one or two instances of "! "...

```
MID(A2,IFERROR(FIND("! ",A2,FIND("! ",A2,1)+1)+2,FIND("! ",A2,1)+2),LEN(A2)-(FIND(" @",A2,1)+2))
```

[image]

Comment: I did not downvote, as any effort is good effort! And it's a good demonstration of the `=MID()` function. But it might be downvoted as it doesn't answer OP's question.

Comment: It always is a 'sport' to get it as short as possible :)

Comment: @JvdV ahh, the time spent looking for shorter versions - probably part of the reason we do what we do...